# typedefs for templated classes?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Is it possible to `typedef` long types that use templates?  For example:

```
template <typename myfloat_t>
class LongClassName
{
    // ...
};

template <typename myfloat_t>
typedef std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< LongClassName<myfloat_t> > > LongCollection;

LongCollection<float> m_foo;
```

This doesn't work, but is there a way to achieve a similar effect?  I just want to avoid having to type and read a type definition that covers almost the full width of my editor window.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, that isn't possible currently. It will be made possible in C++0X AFAIK.

The best I can think of is

```
template<typename T> struct LongCollection {
    typedef std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< LongClassName<T> > > type;
};

LongCollection<float>::type m_foo;
```

Comment: Indeed, duplicate all your ctors??

Comment: No, actually you don't. This idiom is called a 'template metafunction' where the nested ::type is the actual type that's created. This means you don't really construct an instance of LongCollection<...> but rather reach in to get the correct type from LongCollection<...>::type.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go the macro way you have to make individual typedefs for each type:

```
typedef std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< LongClassName<float> > > FloatCollection;
typedef std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< LongClassName<double> > > DoubleCollection;
```

Comment: This is, after all, how std::string is a typedef of std::basic_string.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can get close using a 'helper' type, see this [example](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The solution shown by Leon is canonical. Bit of background knowledge: This is called a “(template) metafunction” because it is basically a “function” that gets evaluated at compile time. Instead of values, it deals with types: There's a list of input types (the type arguments) and there's a “return value”: The typedef that declares the type name “type”.

“Invocation” works analogously to normal function invocation, albeit with a different syntax:

```
// Normal function
result = f(args);

// Metafunction
typedef f<args>::type result;
```

This code construct is an often-used idiom in libraries such as the Boost libraries and even in the STL at one place: `allocator_type::rebind<U>::other` accomplishes the same thing with the only difference that the typedef `type` is called `other`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not exactly what you're asking for, but this might achieve the desired effect depending on your actual situation:

```
template <typename myfloat_t>
class LongClassName
{
    // ...
};

template <typename myfloat_t>
class LongCollection : public std::vector< boost::shared_ptr< LongClassName<myfloat_t> > > 
{
};
```

You may need to add some constructors or operators depending on your needs.

Comment: Isn't deriving from STL collections considered bad?  They do not have virtual functions.  I think it would be safer to implement LongCollection in terms of a std::vector by using is as a member variable. Private inheritance may also be an option.

Comment: It's not considered good practice but it doesn't actually pose the problems you mention as long as you don't intend for polymorphic usage.