# Templated namespaces and typedefs are illeagal -- workarounds?

Tags: c++, function, templates, namespaces, typedef

I have a templated function `fct` that uses some complex data structure based on the template parameter. It also calls some helper functions (templated on the same type) that are in a separate `helpers` namespace and use the same complex data structure. Now it gets really ugly because we cannot make one `typedef` for the complex type that all functions can access:

```
namespace helpers {
  template<class T>
  void h1(const std::vector< std::vector< std::map<T, std::set<T> > > >& bar){
    // ...
  }
}

template<class T>
void fct(const std::vector< std::vector< std::map<T, std::set<T> > > >& bar){
  // ...
  helpers::h1(bar);
}
```

Now I want to make it prettier, by using one typedef that all functions can use.

A templated `typedef` would be nice, but it's not allowed:

```
template<class T> 
typedef std::vector< std::vector< std::map<T, std::set<T> > > > Bar;
```

Another solution would be, I think, to wrap all these functions in a templated `namespace`, but that's not allowed in C++ either (I heard it will be in `C++0x' ...).

We have of course templated classes, but note that I don't really want the user to have to construct an object and call member functions on it. So the workaround I ended up using was to use a templated class where all member functions are `static`:

```
template<class T>
class All {

  typedef std::vector< std::vector< std::map<T, std::set<T> > > > Bar;

  static void fct(const Bar& bar){
    // ...
    h1(bar);
  }

private:
  static void h1(const Bar& bar){
    // ...
  }
};
```

My question is: It's probably a bit funny if large parts of my code are organized like that? After all it's a bit unusual to have many classes with just static member functions? Are there other solutions/workaround that make the "templated typedef" / "templated namespace" possible?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251432/typedefs-for-templated-classes .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are there other solutions/workaround that make the "templated typedef" / "templated namespace" possible?

[GOTW #79: Template Typedef](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm)

[The New C++ Typedef Templates](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403850) (See Section 1: The Problem and Current Workarounds)

Comment: I was going to propose the same solution given in GOTW#79: defining traits. +1

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this question in the post-C++11-world: With C++11, there *is*  a templated `typedef`, it's called `using' (which actually can replace typedef entirely. In the context of the question, here is what we do:

```
template<class T> 
using Bar = std::vector< std::vector< std::map<T, std::set<T> > > >;

namespace helpers {
template<class T>
void h1(const Bar<T>& bar){
    // ...
}
}

template<class T>
void fct(const Bar<T>& bar){
  // ...
  helpers::h1(bar);
}
```

Nice and simple. Sort of.